# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir el index de una tupla sin saber cauntas tuplas tendré como input? python

Tags: python-3.x

Por ejemplo: `Hey, Hi, Bye`
Quiero que se imprima: `0, 'Hey', 1, 'Hi', 2, 'Bye'`

Comment: Hola Alexa C.  te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. El título de la pregunta no termina de quedar muy claro "index de una tupla sin saber cuantas tuplas tendré como input" ¿Tienes una sola tuplas con cadenas, es decir `(Hey, Hi, Bye)` o varias tuplas?. Por otro lado, deberías agregar el código que has intentado para resolver tu problema. Sea como sea, la solución más simple y eficiente la tienes en el built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenida Alexa, por favor date una vuelta por [ask], edita tu pregunta para que sea lo más clara y concreta posible para evitar puntuaciones negativas o reportes.

Answer (score 1):

Con [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) puedes hacer esto:

```py
tupla = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
for index, element in enumerate(tupla):
  print(index, element)
```

El resultado es:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
```